# Timing function in Racket

Tags: time, scheme, racket, timing

The syntax for the timing function in Racket is confusing. If I want to check CPU cycles I should be able to wrap my entire code in `(time codestuff)` and it should produce that should it not? I get an error whenever I try to wrap it in (time).

```
lambda: no expression after a sequence of internal definitions in: lambda
```

What other choices do I have to check CPU usage for running my program in Scheme?

Comment: I don't think `time` is a standard procedure in Scheme. Are you using Racket?

Comment: @Barmar

I am using Racket. I read through some other post here on stack and they mentioned it should work with most versions of Racket.

Comment: You need to edit your post to include the expression you use.. eg. `(time ....)`. Also unless you have `#lang racket` as the first line you need to state the language your code is written in. Racket supports many languages and just a few of them have `time` defined.

Comment: @Jonnyutah You can run your code in (time (your-function)) in Racket. https://gist.github.com/mukeshtiwari/28b8b6230a66ca56123ca5827b3cdf34

Comment: What is "codestuff"? That error occurs in situations like `(lambda (x) (define y 1))`, where the function has no expression in its body, or if you write `(time (define x 1))`.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, time doesn't seem to work if the last form in the time body isn't an expression. Fortunately, `(void)` is an expression that is (relatively) free.<sup>1</sup> You can just add it as the last expression in the body of your time giving you:

```
(time
  .... your code here ....
  (void))
```

So for example, the following code will give you a result like this:

```
> (time
    (define x 
      (for/list ([i (in-range 1000000)])
        i))
    (void))
cpu time: 148 real time: 149 gc time: 124
```

<sub><sup>1</sup>As with anything in CS and timing, whether or not void is going to matter here does depend. But for many cases a single call to void should be fine.</sub>